# How to create a custom route matching pattern in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I need to create this url:

```
www.example.com/directory/[state]-financial-planners
```

Where [state] will be different depending on which link users click...e.g:  **/directory/california-financial-planners** etc. I would like to create those urls with function like `state_directory_path("california")`, and my receiving controller should have a variable params[:state].

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a route with a [Dynamic Segment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments):

```
match '/directory/:state-financial-planners' => 'controller_name#action_method', :as => 'state_directory', :via => :get
```

This dynmic segment is the `:state` part of the route, this will set `param[:state]` in the request. You will need to specify `'controller_name#action_method'` with the controller and action that will handle the request